# Project Euler #206

Tags: algorithm, range, sqrt

I was solving problem 206 of project Euler from Hackerrank's competitive set [here.](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler206/problem)

**It states -**

Find the unique positive integer whose square's decimal representation has the form -

[image]

where  [image] are known single digits and  [image] are unknown single digits.

In other words, find the unique positive integer when given the every other digit of its square, starting with the first digit and including the last digit of the square.

**My Algorithm:**

Before any optimizations, I have developed the most obvious algorithm. Say, for example, the input is **8_7_6**, where _'s are unknown digits.

As we know that, we have to find x such that **x^2 takes the form 8_7_6**.

The *range* of x is nothing but, **x = [ sqrt(80706), sqrt(89796) ] = [ 284, 299 ]**.

Now, I run a loop in this range squaring every number. The correct result comes out at **286**, which gives - **286^2 =** **8**1**7**9**6**.

Now, I don't understand the flaw in this algorithm. Any number outside the range can never be an answer, right?. I will optimize the code with the properties of squares (like in this case, we could have just checked **{284, 286, 294, 296}** because *since the unit digit of the given input is 6, x must have either 4 or 6 in the unit's place*) so that the number of iterations is minimized.

> **But the problem is, Hackerrank shows me that my algorithm gives the wrong answer in certain test cases. At some, the time limit exceeds,
> which is absolutely fine since I have not yet optimized my code, but
> why "wrong answer"?**

ps: This passed in the first 8 test cases though.

Comment: There is no way your described algorithm could give the wrong answer. Maybe there is a flaw in your *implementation*.

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: Maybe an issue with int overflow. Did you use 32-bit integers?

Comment: So, Hackerrank is a website that just copies the problems from project Euler?

Comment: Project Euler [question 206](https://projecteuler.net/problem=206) is a much more limited case where the target number has every other digit predefined: 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_0  This is a more generalised version of that question.

Comment: @Olivier I changed int to unsinged long long, but it still shows wrong answer.. :(

Comment: Do you verify the answer or not? The bounds are actually [ceil(sqrt(...)), floor(sqrt(...))]. It could be that you find an answer which is not in range.

Comment: @StrangerForever: You seem to be asking us to figure out the bug in your code without actually showing us the code. That's not going to be easy.